# Error when setting flashing port: "A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB1, the port doesn't exist"

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, espressif-idf

I have ESP32 module connected to my Windows machine. And I have project in Visual Studio Code with Espressife IDF plugin. Device is connected with COM5. Whole project was coppyed from other machine. Got error while trying to flash:

```
A fatal error occurred: Could not open /dev/ttyUSB1, the port doesn't exist
```

I see button /dev/ttyUSB1 in bottom left corner, but I can't change it. I suppose this setting sets port in development container that is mapped to Windows COM5?

How to know which port in development container was used and how to set it?

[image]